# What happens when a photon interacts with a free electron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, electromagnetic-radiation

When an electromagnetic wave interacts with a free electron the electron starts to oscillate in the direction perpendicular to the propagation of the wave meanwhile when a photon interacts with a free electron what will the electron do?

1. Will it oscillate in the direction perpendicular to the momentum of the photon?
   or
   will it travel in the direction of the momentum of photon?
2. How can someone describe this interaction in photons form so that the electrons oscillates?

Comment: you need quantum electrodynamics to model it. https://sites.ualberta.ca/~gingrich/courses/phys512/node102.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the classical theory, for a linearly polarized plane EM wave, the electron oscillates in the polarization direction, perpendicular to the propagation direction. An oscillating charge emits radiation in a dipole pattern, so this means the electron intercepts some of the energy and scatters it ([Thomson scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_scattering)).

There is also momentum transfer from the wave to the electron in the direction of propagation. This is difficult to account for in the microscopic classical theory, although the average over time is just the momentum the scattered component would have if it wasn't scattered.

For photon energies below the keV range, the classical model works fine. The momentum transfer per photon hardly affects the trajectory of the electron: it's too heavy.

For higher energies, electron recoil in a single photon collision is important. Here, we call the process [Compton scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering), and classical models are not adequate. As anna v notes, you need a quantum electrodynamic model.